# Tools for non regression testing on REST API?

Tags: symfony, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have developed a project with a symfony server as backend and a mobile application as frontend.

I am unemployed but I hope to start my own business :)

What tool(s) should I use for non regression testing ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't use API Platform. It provides the [ApiTestCase](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/testing/#testing-the-api) that provides several assertions to test JSON responses :

```php
class BooksTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    // This trait provided by AliceBundle will take care of refreshing the database content to a known state before each test
    use RefreshDatabaseTrait;

    public function testGetCollection(): void
    {
        // The client implements Symfony HttpClient's `HttpClientInterface`, and the response `ResponseInterface`
        $response = static::createClient()->request('GET', '/books');

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        // Asserts that the returned content type is JSON-LD (the default)
        $this->assertResponseHeaderSame('content-type', 'application/ld+json; charset=utf-8');

        // Asserts that the returned JSON is a superset of this one
        $this->assertJsonContains([
            '@context' => '/contexts/Book',
            '@id' => '/books',
            '@type' => 'hydra:Collection',
            'hydra:totalItems' => 100,
            'hydra:view' => [
                '@id' => '/books?page=1',
                '@type' => 'hydra:PartialCollectionView',
                'hydra:first' => '/books?page=1',
                'hydra:last' => '/books?page=4',
                'hydra:next' => '/books?page=2',
            ],
        ]);
```

As you can see, in this example, the `/books` endpoint of the API is tested. But you can also use the standard `WebTestCase` provided by Symfony to do this manually.